# Can the French create 2 forts?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

In the original Age of Empire 3, can the French create 2 forts or 2 factories ? If yes, How ?

Comment: I'd imagine via home city cards. Have you had a look through what's available?

Comment: I do get 1 factory and 1 fort card. But some online resources say 2 are possible which left me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With French you can have **three** Forts. The first card is available to you early, but the other two cards require a Level 25 Home City and can only be used in Age 4, while the first one can be used in Age 3.

You can also have **two** factories, but of course in order to have all 5 you need to give up other cards.